# Indicate depth of org-mode header level?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** is there a way to indicate the depth of an `org` header by number?

I often use deep nests of `org` headers, e.g.:

```
* header 1
** more
*** still more
**** yet more
***** still going
****** don't judge me
** another subheader
*** here we go again
**** sweet cuppin' cakes
***** puppies
```

It's easy to lose track of the depth of the header after third or
fourth level.  Is there a way to get a visual indicator of the
depth (maybe with an overlay?) somewhere on the header?  For
example, an overlay over the first `*` to indicate the numerical
level, as with the following hypothetical:

```
1 header 1
2* more
3** still more
4*** yet more
5**** still going
6***** don't judge me
2* another subheader
3** here we go again
4*** sweet cuppin' cakes
5**** puppies
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the [org-bullets](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets) package for reference on precisely how to do this.  The essential component is the minor mode definition.  The level can be judged from the length of the `org-outline-regexp-bol` match (`(- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0) 1)`). 
 I prefer to use the 'display property rather than the composition mechanism.

I might also suggest using circled unicode numbers to make your outline really "pop" ;-)

```
① header 1
 ② more
  ③ still more
...
```

I've included my function to look up those characters.

```
(require 'org-bullets)
(require 'nxml-mode)

(define-minor-mode org-my-bullets-level-mode
  "UTF-8 bullets for `org-mode' indicating declarative sort of headings."
  nil nil nil
  (let* ((keyword
          `((,org-outline-regexp-bol
             (0 (progn
                  ;; Set the bullet display character
                  (put-text-property (- (match-end 0) 2)
                                     (- (match-end 0) 1)
                                     'display
                                     (circled-number-unicode-char (- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0) 1)))
                  (when (facep org-bullets-face-name)
                    ;; Set bullet face
                    (put-text-property (- (match-end 0) 2)
                                       (- (match-end 0) 1)
                                       'face
                                       org-bullets-face-name))
                  ;; "Hide" leading '*'s
                  (put-text-property (match-beginning 0)
                                     (- (match-end 0) 2)
                                     'face (list :foreground
                                                 (face-attribute
                                                  'default :background)))
                  ;; Attach the keymap to the entire segment
                  (put-text-property (match-beginning 0)
                                     (match-end 0)
                                     'keymap
                                     org-bullets-bullet-map)
                  nil))))))
    (if org-my-bullets-level-mode
        (progn (font-lock-add-keywords nil keyword)
               (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (font-lock-remove-keywords nil keyword)))))

(defun circled-number-unicode-char (num)
  "Return the corresponding circled digit unicode character for NUM.  Number range: -20 to 50."
  (let ((charcode (cond
                   ((and (>= num -20)
                         (<= num -11))
                    (+ (abs num) 9440))
                   ((and (>= num -10)
                         (<= num -1))
                    (+ (abs num) 10101))
                   ((= num 0)
                    9450)
                   ((and (>= num 1)
                         (<= num 20))
                    (+ 9311 num))
                   ((and (>= num 21)
                         (<= num 35))
                    (+ 12860 num))
                   ((and (>= num 36)
                         (<= num 50))
                    (+ 12941 num)))))
    (char-to-string (xmltok-unicode-to-char charcode))))
```

It looks like this on my system:

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: Hmm, when I turn on your minor mode, it depropertizes everything, and does not show the bullets as you defined them.

Comment: @Dan just a guess: `xmltok-unicode-to-char` is undefined and the lack of error handling might be breaking your fontification. Try `(require 'nxml)` and reloading. If that's not it do you get any messages?

Comment: Yup, it was `(require 'nxml-mode)` that was missing.  I've added it to your code.  Thank you!